# Is it known whether there are infinitely many Newman-Shanks-Williams (NSW) primes?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

The sequence of NSW numbers is defined by the expression $$s_{2m+1}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{2m+1}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{2m+1}}{2}$$ for $m=0,1,2,3,...$. If $s_{2m+1}$ is prime, it is called an NSW prime.

One can also describe the NSW numbers by the recurrence relation: $$s_0=1,s_1=1, s_n=2s_{n-1}+s_{n-2}\text{ for n}\geq 2.$$

It was conjectured in the original 1980 paper "Simple groups of square order and an interesting sequence of primes" by Newman, Shanks, and Williams that there are infinitely many NSW primes. However, I cannot find any sources that indicate whether any progress has been made on this question since then.

Is it known today whether there are infinitely many NSW primes? Has any other progress been made on this question since that paper?

Comment: I suspect it's unknown, much as for other exponential sequences such as the Marsenne primes.

Comment: Must the index $n$ in $s_n$ be odd ?

Comment: $s_n$ is prime for the following $n's$ (the only odd in this list is $3$. I wonder whether we can prove it is the only one) :  2 3 4 6 10 12 16 18 22 30 42 60 78 100 126 166 190 198 312 346 700 1708 2616 3538 5806 (search limit : 10 000)

Comment: To prove that a sequence contains infinite many primes is usually out of reach, but with respect to the growth rate and that small factors are apparently not forced , infinite many such primes should exist.

Comment: Yes, that recurrence only gives NSW numbers for odd $n$. OEIS A002135 is the entry for NSW numbers, and there the recurrence $S_0=1$, $S_1=7$, and $S_n=6S_{n-1}-S_{n-2}$ for $n\geq 2$ is given, and OEIS A088165 gives the indices of prime NSW numbers with respect to that sequence: 1, 2, 3, 9, 14, 23, 29, 81, 128, 210, 468, 473, 746, 950, 3344, 4043, 4839, 14376, 39521, 64563, 72984, 82899, 84338, 85206, 86121, 139160...

Comment: $s_6=99$, no? I have $s_n$ corresponding to OEIS A001333. (w/ $s_0=s_1=1$)

Comment: In my comment, "Marsenne" should, of course, be "Mersenne". A shame that one cannot edit comments.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In this case , I usually delete the comment and post it again , unless the typo is irrelevant.